# Programmatically stop JavaScript execution in Firebug

Tags: javascript, debugging, firebug, breakpoints

I am currently debugging complex JavaScript code with Firebug. I am looking for a way to stop the JavaScript execution as if it was a breakpoint programmatically.

Example:

```
instructions ...
degugger.breakpoint(); // the execution stops here as if a breakpoint was
                       // manually set
other instructions ...
```

Answer (score 122):

You can use the [`debugger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger) statement:

```
// your JS code
...
// break here
debugger;
```

It works in all major browsers.

Comment: It will also work with IE if you enable Script Debugging in the Internet Options.

Comment: After you have done this, you should be then be able to use breakpoints in your IDE debugger. This saves you from having to declare multiple 'debugger;' lines of code across your application.

Comment: I'm surprised how long I've gone without realizing you could do this. Thanks, this is very helpful. I would add that, for Chromium on Linux, this line of code will only pause execution if the debugger is open (and the disable breakpoints toggle is not selected).

Comment: this didn't work for me in firefox.  Do you have to have the debugger open?  I had firebug open but was looking at the console + network tabs.  I wasn't actually interested in the code/state at the time but just wanted the console output to stop

Comment: The debugger directive now works in Opera. (Tested in Opera 28)