# Chrome - Prevent scripts from running in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

Is there anyway to prevent changes to web pages such as a live chat or a video feed? Im guessing its a javascript that times out the webpage and then exits it or prevents further entry.

I saw this question: [Freeze screen in chrome debugger / DevTools panel for popover inspection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17931571/freeze-screen-in-chrome-debugger-devtools-panel-for-popover-inspection)

What I did was I inspected the element, then went to the line of code and then clicked on :hover but the script still executed and locked me out. Any other ways you can think of to prevent changes being made to a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How to deliberately freeze javascript in chrome (plugin/console)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17497912/how-to-deliberately-freeze-javascript-in-chrome-plugin-console)

Found another solution in the link above:

1. Open Chrome javascript console
2. Go to "sources"
3. On the right side, click the little "pause" icon, or press F8 to pause script execution.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome allows you to disable JavaScript on certain pages, to do so click on the globe of the URL bar and it will show some permission options for the site you are. There disable JavaScript.

Comment: Awesome! I'll try this out, limiting permissions for a page might work too!