# Chrome Developer Tools breakpoints - weird behavior

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I use Chrome Developer Tools to inspect a page online and hit debugger breakpoints in the site's scripts. I did not set these breakpoints. How are they there?

[image: screen grab of chrome developer tools display vm 183 tab]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they are error/exception breakpoints. Check if pause on exceptions is enabled, or step over and check if exceptions appears in the console.

[image]

**Edit**: other posibility is that code include debugger instructions (debugger statement...) as defined in [Programmatically stop JavaScript execution in Firebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265623/programmatically-stop-javascript-execution-in-firebug)

Comment: No. That control is not activated. The breakpoint brings up a tab "VM 153" that has a function debugger()

Comment: Then it could be the debugger instructions as defined in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265623/programmatically-stop-javascript-execution-in-firebug

Comment: Silly me. Debugging and breakpoint functionality did not used to come natively in the browser. Breakpoints had to be written in manually.